# Transpose column data to rows based on common ID in one column using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I transpose column data to rows based on common ID in one column using SQL.
for example

I have the given data to be,

```
| ID | data |
|----|------|
| 1  | d1   |
| 2  | d2   |
| 3  | d3   |
| 1  | d4   |
| 2  | d5   |
```

I need,

```
| ID |   data  |
|----|---------|
| 1  | d1 | d4 |
| 2  | d2 | d5 |
| 3  | d3      |
```

How can I achieve this in SQL

Comment: Why does d1come before d4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `group_concat()`:

```
select id, group_concat(data separator ' | ') as data
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked Amazing!

Comment: @SahilAnand . . . The question is tagged MySQL, not SQL Server.  You should pay attention to the tags, and you can probably find the information you need.  Otherwise, ask a new question.